# Google Nearby Message API notifications when app is closed?

Tags: android, ios, eddystone, google-nearby, google-beacon-platform

I wonder if there is any way to configure an app(Android and iOS) using native Google Nearby Message API sdk to get eddystone beacons notifications when the app is completely closed?.

Right now I have background scanning configured and it's working OK, but I also need to support the case when the app is closed. Thanks, Jose.

Comment: See if a service could scan the beacons for you

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library)  to do the background detection for initially launch your app.  Once running, you can continue to use this library to process detections or start using Nearby APIs at that time.

To auto launch in the background  on detection, see the "Starting an App in the Background" section [here](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html)

You will need to register the Eddystone beacon parser like this: `beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));`. You can read more about using the library with Eddystone [here](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/eddystone-how-to.html)